# goquery get all <p> tags from just one selector

Tags: javascript, go, goquery

I have the following example

```
<div class="myClass"> 
    <div> 
        <div> 
            <p>1</p> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
        <p>2</p> 
    <div> 
    </div> 
    <p>3</p> 
</div>
```

How can I extract the 3 p tags using goquery or CSS selectors (or both)
Maybe in this case the selector would be "div.myClass"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all child elements of `.myClass` with a selector like this:

```css
.myClass p {
    /* Selects all p elements that descend from .myClass */
}
```

A guide about *descendant selectors* can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Answer (score 1):

just `p {/* Selects all p elements */}`